# Change Eclipse's tooltip/hint/sugestions/overlay window color

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes, look-and-feel

I have spent the last couple of hours trying to figure this out, but with no success.

I recently changed to a dark theme but I'm having problems reading the tooltip/hint/sugestions/overlay window *(don't know what to call it, since I already saw people calling all this different names)*, to a more readable format without having to click on it to be able to read it.

Already tried switching the windows tooltips colors, as suggested on other posts but without success. **I'm using Windows 7.**

As you can see from the following screenshots, when the *tooltip/hint/sugestions/overlay window* is displayed it's pretty unreadable, and it's very annoying to have to click on it to make it readable.

Any way on how I can change the unfocused background color or all the text colors?

**Without** focus

[image: Without focus]

**With** focus

[image: With focus]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I asked this question I was using Eclipse Luna and never found a solution for this problem.

More recently I changed to Eclipse Neon and this problem never occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window->Preferences and there under General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts on the right list under Basic->Content Assist background Color. This should switch the background color

Comment: Didn't work. The color for the Content Assist Background Color was white and it shows black :S

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @NerdNeo, you should go to

- *Window > Preferences* and then from there
- *General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*

In the list, after checking *Basic > Content Assist Background Color*,  you should also ensure that *Java > Javadoc background* and *Java > Javadoc text color* are set to contrasting colors.